# Rails 6 Font Awesome 5 Production Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, font-awesome, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a REALLY strange problem with my Rails 6 application in production mode. I deployed a new version without changing anything for webpacker and suddenly my Font Awesome 5 Icons are not loading anymore. I tried EVERYTHING that I could think of but nothing works.
In development, my Icons are loading without problems, no errors are displayed.
Then if I deploy my app with Capistrano everything works, but the icon won't display.

```
# application.scss
$fa-font-path: '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts'; 
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';

# application.js
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all";
```

I don't know a few days ago everything worked fine, my icons were showing in development and production environment and suddenly, I can do what I want, it's broken:

[image]

I don't know how I got this error, I'm using Phusion Passenger with NGINX, but changed nothing on the config. I made sure the webfonts are present in the right folder, but I keep getting this error.
I don't know why the connection should be refused, the other webfonts that are present are available it seems.

EDIT:
I tried to clear my browser cache, I tried ipconfig /flushdns and I tested it on my mobile phone etc, everywhere I get the same error.

EDIT2:
If I delete the fonts from the packs director, I get the following error:

> Access to font at
>   'http://localhost:3000/packs/media/webfonts/fa-solid-900-f6121be5.woff2'
>   from origin 'http://webmenue2019.de' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

EDIT3:
I noticed while digging in Chrome that those webfonts are being loaded from localhost:3000! But why?

[image]

Comment: Nobody knows what to do? :/

Answer (score 4):

i have the same problem too, my fixes was i removed all font awesome `@import` in `application.scss` and add this to my `application.js`:

```js
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all";
```

Comment: I'm curious what your webpack config looks like. I get errors when trying to import css into my js